# Detect faces on an image captured in Android OpenCV java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

When touch on the screen, this method is invoked, highgui.imwrite is suppose to overwrite the previous store into sdcard method.

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");

     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
     String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
     String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                               "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
     mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
     Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Mat a = Highgui.imread(fileName);

  MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();


  if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
      if (mJavaDetector != null)
  mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(a, faceDetections);
  }
  else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
      if (mNativeDetector != null)
          mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faceDetections);
  }
  else {
      Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
  }


     for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()){

       Core.rectangle(a, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
      Boolean bool = null;
      bool =   Highgui.imwrite(fileName,a);
     if (bool == true)
        Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS writing image to external storage");
      else
        Log.d(TAG, "Fail writing image to external storage");

    }
    return false;
}
```

Then this method will create fileName for storing in external storage and takes the picture.

```
public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Taking picture");
            this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
            // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
            // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue   

            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

            // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class    

            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);        
        }
```

This method takes bytes array and store into sdcard.

```
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
    // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
    mCamera.startPreview();

  //...

    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

    // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);

        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();

    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    }



}
```

Now I believe I have converted to type Mat with highgui.imread(directory).
But now I want to able to detect faces on that image with rectangle then store the image in sdcard using high.imwrite but when i open the image it does not have the rectangle on faces.
Any idea or suggestions on what Im doing wrong? Any reply is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked whether your `mNativeDetector.detect(mGray,faceDetections)' works as expected? Do **rect.x** and **rect.y** have valid values in relation to the face in the image?

Comment: First off, thanks for replying and yes because it is able to detect face on live camera preview. Then now I want to be able to detect faces on a static image. I seem to have realize a problem is that. Highgui.imwrite fails to write a new image file. I am not sure why.

Comment: Have you also made sure to add writing permission to the manifest? `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Yep. I was able to create a file with the onPictureTaken method. But what I am trying to do is extracting the image with imread then detect face then imwrite. This is where it is not working.

Comment: Just to make it clear: Is the writing successful (log: SUCCESS writing image to external storage), but the image hasn't changed? If so, have you tried printing the points on another `mat` (a blank one) and writing that to the SD and see what happens?